# What alternatives exist for running QTP tests in batch?

Tags: automated-tests, qtp

We are in the process of implementing automated regression testing for our applications, and are looking for a solid batch-testing utility.  We have QuickTest Professional 10.0, and it comes bundled with 'Test Batch Runner' which appears to be deprecated.  It appears in previous versions there was 'Multi-Test Manager', which has been discontinued as well.

What alternatives exist, if any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The canonical way to do this is via [Quality Center](https://h10078.www1.hp.com/cda/hpms/display/main/hpms_content.jsp?zn=bto&cp=1-11-127-24_4000_100__), if you don't have QC you can use QTP's automation model from a `vbs` file. The documentation for this is available in `Start -> Programs -> QuickTest Professional -> Documentation -> Automation Object Model Reference`

Answer (score 3):

QTP 10 works excellent with Multi Test Manager V8.2.4.

We use it for our project (previously used it with QTP 9.2).

Try google for an installation (of you don't have one), it should be free but just not supported by HP anymore.

Answer (score 1):

From WinRunner times I very extensively used Test Driver scripts with great success due to the following benefits:

- non-programming testers can easily create/maintain batches as their stored in XML format
- test input files are externally configurable through mapping
- a variety of customization parameters supported, from login credentials to prefixes and switches
- test dependencies could be established so that if critical test cases is failed the whole branch of dependant test cases is skipped.

Now I continue using Test Drivers and introducing them to clients. 
And Test Driver approach was integrated not only by the client companies that do not use Quality Center. Some others followed it because it gives much more flexibility and robustness in automated test plan execution.

Thank you,
Albert Gareev

http://automationbeyond.wordpress.com

Answer (score 0):

I echo Motti...if i get your question right ....You can see the below written link as well..
[Work with Test Batch runner](https://techtravelhub.com/what-is-test-batch-runner-in-uft-qtp/)